# SharePoint 2013 redirection after submitting popup form

Tags: 2013, form, redirect

I'm very new to SharePoint and stuck on below:

I have a site with loads of events and all of those events uses 1 registration form. Every time a user wants to register to an event they have to navigate to the actual event page and then click 'Register' which open up the form in a separate browser window.

What I want to do is to redirect the actual event page to a 'Thank you' page once the form is submitted.

My problem is, as I'm getting the user to fill the form in a separate window how do I get the actual event page to be redirected which sits in the background.

Answer (score 1):

**Briefly:** Create a custom "Thank you"-page referred as the source in a custom "New Item"-button.

**More detailed:** When the default "New Item"-form is opened, it's done through an URL where the source is referred as

```
http://site/List/Forms/NewItem.aspx?Source=http://site/page.aspx
```

You can create your custom "New Item"-button which directs to the given URL. When the form is submitted (= new item is added), it redirects back to `http://site/page.aspx` which can be your page indicating thanks and what ever you prefer to have there.

SPServices, a kind of toolkit library for SharePoint, provides a jQuery alternative for redirecting as well. You can read about it [here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPRedirectWithID).